# "Me" vs "I" - when it's correct to use "Me" and when it's correct to use "I"

Tags: pronouns

I'm always confused when it's correct to use "Me" and when it's correct to use "I"?

Can I always replace "I" by "me" (not opposite)? 
Some examples: 
"Me and you went together there" 
"I and you went together there"

For the moment I'm using me just in the end of the sentence or when I'm talking about me and someone else together. But I sometimes hear people that replace the two pronouns. Maybe here I'll solve the problem and I'll Know what is the correct way.

Comment: This question has been asked many time in the past. Yet people don't research it. [First question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me), [Second Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/my-friends-and-i-vs-my-friends-and-me-vs-me-and-my-friends), [Third Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream-should-i-say-not-i-or-not-me), and [Fourth Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8353/me-versus-i),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorrect usage of these terms is one of the most common errors native English speakers make.

They are definitely not interchangeable.

For a newcomer to the English language, the rule can be summarized like this:

- **"I" is a subject**. The subject is the person/thing that is *doing* something.
- **"Me" is an object**.  The object is the one being affected by or related to the subject's action.  Again, if the verb is "see," the object is the person/thing that the subject "sees," "is seeing," "saw," "will see," etc.

Consider these examples:

- "I see you."  "I" is the subject and "you" is the object.
- "You see me."  "You" is the subject and "me" is the object.

This is a *gross* oversimplification, but it's a solid starting point.

Using this same logic, let's assume you are asked the question, "Who did that?"  Refer to my rule above, where I said, "The subject is the one that is *doing* something."  The correct answer would be "I," "I did," or "I did that."  In colloquial speaking, however, a majority of native English speakers would likely respond "me," but ironically, the same people would never say "me did" or "me did that."  The easiest way to speak grammatically correctly *and* sound completely natural is to simply include the verb in your response: "I did."

Also, keep in mind that "I" and "me" always come last in a series of nouns and/or pronouns.  "You and I went together" is correct, while "I and you went together" is not.  Some examples:

- "John, Maria, and I studied together last night."  "I" must come last in the list of subjects who studied together.
- "The professor helped John, Maria, and me study last night."  "Me" must come last in the list of objects who were helped by the professor.

It's just a hard rule: include "I" and "me" last whenever you have a series of two or more subjects/objects listed together.

Comment: Can you explain please the last your clause? I mean to:  ""You and I went together" is correct, while "I and you went together" is not." What is the difference between them?

Comment: Sure.  Whenever you are speaking in the 1st person (i.e. you're talking about yourself, using "I" or "me"), and there is another subject or object involved, the rule is simple: always include the 1st-person pronoun last.  Another example: use "John, Maria, and I studied together" but never "I, John, and Maria" or "John, I, and Maria."  By rule, "I" will always be the last when you have more than one subject/object listed together.

Comment: I added some additional example content to my answer.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Please add some information about using "me" as an answer on questions. eg. "Who did that?" what is the correct answer, "me" or "I"?

Comment: The technically correct answer is "I," but take a look at the detail I added to my response above.

Comment: I read all what you wrote, but I unfortunately I didn't understand the answer clearly. When you say that "The technically correct answer is "I"", what do you mean? you mean that it's actually if I say "I" it sounds weird?

Comment: Depending on the environment, it *could* sound weird, because "me" is so commonly misused as a subject.  To avoid both improper grammar and sounding weird, just include the verb with the subject.  Respond with "I did" instead of just "I."  This is both correct and will sound completely natural.